# Ubuntu willl not boot after update

Tags: boot, kernel, updates

I tried turning on my laptop, but I keep receiving this screen. I'm not sure how to fix this. If I boot into recovery mode in a lower version it works, but not well. It becomes very glitchy, and I can't move the mouse. It hangs on the same screen as well.

[image]

Comment: Improve your question by specifying what you were updating, and from which version to which?

Comment: I just ran the system update, didnt really pay attention. But this is what I get when it boots. Here is a pic https://imgur.com/FsomFqX   If i select the 0-24 I get the screen i posted above. But if I select the other ones it will load but it will be very glitchy and I cant do anything.

Comment: I think your partition or hard disk is corrupted. Re-install if everything fails

Comment: I can boot into like 3.11.0-12 but i just cant access like my settings. its anything after that that the problems get worse.

Comment: It's possible that you installed a kernel update that went wrong. Try choosing the previous kernel in the grub menu from the second option in the list.

Comment: when I boot into the second option it says "An error occurred while mounting /boot"

Answer (score 0):

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image
```

Try this in the terminal of one of your functional kernels. Then reboot and choose the newest option in Grub.

If that doesn't work, I'd grab your live-cd, and either reinstall completely, or, `chroot` into your install and try to re-install things that way.

Comment: only problem is it wont even connect to a network. Its a ultrabook so only wireless.

Comment: Well if the core utilities for your kernel are still functional, then you will be able to connect to wireless. Unfortunately I do not how to connect to wireless via the command on Ubuntu, only on Arch Linux. :(